# how to fix this problem with Visual studio Installer "unable to download installation files unable to check your internet connection and try again"

Tags: visual-studio

so i am trying to install Visual studio on my windows 7 laptop, i downloaded the installer from the official site, i opened the installer and start downloading the installation file, the download is stuck at 0% saying its 0B to 0B download and after a while of waiting it says "unable to download installation files unable to check your internet connection and try again", please help

i have tried changing the services,msn and gpedit.msc settings but its already as what it supposed to be and i tried vpn and it also failed